# how decode this JSON answer form server?

Tags: json

I have JSON response from server, but I don't how to decode it and read.

```
{"data":"hX8L^^\u0002@[ZUN\\r[\\A\\6V\u0017\fq\u0012\u0004P^U_\u0016\u0005\u0006\u0017\u0000'FWPM\u0003LZ\u0010gHsF\u000e\u0012UE\u0012\t\u000fM#:\u0003A~VKb\u0015\u001dO\u0014\u0012\u0006pQ\u0005\u0005\u0010\u000b\u0001\u001d/\u0000A\u0014ke\u0015Y\u0004l|@K&\t\u0017uqJ>`r\fBK)Yf\u0015ZO\u000bfG'MO\b_mob\n\u0004KyQO\tRkuYJcZ\u0016uBb|dt\u0012Xt\f\u0006H\u001cz\u00162\u0003T\u001eWJ4azw\u001dR\u00104WZ\u0001w\u0013\u0000lbS@!@\u00055#Q'X\u0005-N@@\u0010\\+D\u0005\u0003\u0018h+JL..Dk\u0005\u000bre\r\u0013YK&]R7\u0010k\u0016e\u0013q\u0003\u0015\n\u0002\u0012p\u0002\u0016$&@...
```

is there any converter?

thx

Comment: What type of data are you expecting?

Comment: it should be list like this:
word=123
word2=34556
word3=549
...

I think, on original site this data decode some JS. I just repeat request by my prog, but data encoded :(